# Can a Java EE6 filter be defined with an annotation but applied in the web.xml?

Tags: java, java-ee-6, servlet-filters, web.xml

I have written a filter which i think would be generally useful in many web applications. I would like to put it in a library (packaged as a jar file), so that it can be distributed and used. However, i don't want to force users of the library to use it (it's just one of many wonderful things in it).

At the moment, the filter looks like this:

```
public class WonderfulFilter implements Filter {
```

Which means that to apply it, users have to add the following to their web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>WonderfulFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.example.WonderfulFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WonderfulFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In the brave new EE6 world, this seems ungainly.

If i define the filter like this:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class WonderfulFilter implements Filter {
```

Then no configuration is needed to apply the filter. But there is also no option to *not* apply the filter.

What can i do? Is there any way to annotate a filter to define its URL pattern (and other properties) without implicitly applying it? Is there any way to easily disable a filter in the web.xml?

(there may be a sort-of solution involving a web-fragment.xml; will look into that ...)

Comment: now you want to apply this to all apps running on a given server? or only to ones using the jar which contains your filter?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use an annotation here. It's not configurable by the user (what if I only want the filter applied to a specific pattern?) and then imho even worse just including the library suddenly filters all requests implicitly - for an optional feature that's not wanted. Now you could change the behavior of the annotation based on some property file to get the wanted behavior, but then what's the difference of using `web.xml` in the first place?

Comment: @havexz: I want to apply it to all apps using the jar *and* which have explicitly enabled it.

Comment: @Voo: The settings in the annotation can all be overridden by the web.xml, so they should perhaps be seen as defaults rather than final values. I think for many apps, `/*` would be a sensible path for this filter (it does some very generic authentication handling), but certainly, the final decision must be in the hands of users.

Answer (score 1):

You could ship your web filter with the annotation but have its behavior activated/deactivated via an externalizable property. From your description it sounds like you would like the web filter to be *inactive* by default, which makes sense. Just add documentation that makes the third parties aware of which property they need to enable to turn the filter on.

Answer (score 1):

The part of the @WebFilter annotation which applies the filter is the urlPatterns attribute. If that is left out, the filter will not be applied to any requests.

Thus, the class can be declared:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "WonderfulFilter")
public class WonderfulFilter implements Filter {
```

And in the application's web.xml, the user can then write:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WonderfulFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Yes, they still have to supply the mapping, including the URL pattern, themself. But at least they don't have to write the filter definition. They are therefore insulated from the specific name of the filter class, and are relieved of the responsibility of supplying any mandatory init-params.

It's not much of an improvement.

Comment: If you passing this as library have you thought if two filters comes with the same name 'WonderfulFilter'?

Comment: @havexz: I'm actually using a format like org.example.WonderfulFilter as the name, ie a reverse-domain-name format, which should avoid collisions.